# How to give index items different background images

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have an index view displaying multiple items with background images. The url is a string product.image. Here is my index view.

```
<div class="products">

      <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <style>
          .product-image-index {
            background-image: url('<%= product.image %>');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          }
      </style>
      <div class="product-con">
        <div class="product-image-index">
        </div>
        <div class="product-text">
          <div class="title"><%= product.name %></div>
          <div class="button-con">
            <span class="button"><%= link_to 'More Info', product, class: "buton" %></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

The problem is the background images have the same image, and I understand, but what is the solution to this problem so that each item shows their respective background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either:

1. Make a separate CSS class for each of your images.
2. Make the `background-image` CSS inline, inside your HTML:

---

```
<style>
.product-image-index{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>

<div class="products">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="product-con">
        <div class="product-image-index" style="background-image: url('<%= @product.image %>');"></div>
        <div class="product-text">
            <div class="title"><%= product.name %></div>
            <div class="button-con">
                <span class="button"><%= link_to 'More Info', product, class: "buton" %></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

In most situations using the `style` attribute is "bad": HTML should contain content, not CSS. But I make an exception with background images in situations like these, since they behave like content.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a CSS class where the background image will most likely be the last image in the loop. You will want to remove the line that sets the image:

```
.product-image-index {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Also, move the style definition to an external stylesheet, or at least out of the loop because you are re-defining that class N times inside of the loop.

And add an inline style to the element like so:

`<div class="product-image-index" style="background-image: url('<%= product.image %>');">`